# my mail sender codes fails with gmail lately

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I used this code to sending mail with gmail! before it works very well but now it fails! (it is in c# and form application)

```
cmdSend.Text = "Wait!";
cmdSend.Enabled = false;
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(txtMailAddressFrom.Text);
mail.To.Add(txtMailAddressTo.Text);
mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
string htmlBody;
htmlBody = txtMailBody.Text;
mail.Body = htmlBody;
SmtpServer.Port = 578;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtMailAddressFrom.Text, txtPassword.Text);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
SmtpServer.Dispose();
cmdSend.Text = "Send";
cmdSend.Enabled = true;
```

I tested with port 465 but don't work!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Gmail use port 587 and not 578?